# How to get Belgium tourist visa (family visit visa) with maximum validity?

Tags: tourist-visas, belgium, family

I will be moving to Belgium next month on work permit and later after couple of months I want to bring my mother too.
I know tourist visa ( purpose - family visit) will be provided with maximum 90 days validity. 
What is the required procedure to get visa with maximum validity.
Is it okay if I book return ticket on 80th day from her date of arrival and provide necessary financial supporting documents for all the 80 days of her stay will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When your mother applies for her tourist visa, she has to explain the premise of her trip. If she can explain how staying for 90 days is genuine tourism and that she will *definitively* leave with no fuss after 90 days, then those 90 days should be granted.

Unfortunately your plans don't *sound* like typical tourism. Belgium has some nice places, but 80 days isn't the normal tourist trip. Clearly she wants to visit you, and the assumption will be that you want to care for her or she wants to case for your family. It will sound worse if you have children.

So the way to go is this:

- Ask for 80 or even 90 days.
- Provide **solid** evidence of her continuing ties to her home country, and of her intention to leave.

An alternative might be to look at a family reunion visa. For that, ask on Expatriates SE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply @o.m Small correction in my above question actually I mentioned tourist visa for her but now only I'm aware there is family visit visa (link : https://dofi.ibz.be/sites/dvzoe/EN/Application-guides/Pages/Short_stay_for_private_reasons_Visiting_family_or_friends.aspx)

Comment: And can I show fixed deposit(1.5 lakh INR) in her name as evidence for her ties to home country

Comment: @user1995151, I'm not sure the deposit would help *much*. If I get the conversion right, those are some 2000 EUR, which is **not much** when it comes to living in the EU. Besides, if she were to overstay there might be ways to transfer the money.